# Issues creating todo list

Tags: javascript

I have tried to create the todo list in JavaScript only. I want to append the content while inserting the text by endusers. Here I have placed my code.

```
function Add(){
    var a, input, ul, ulAttr, li;
    function button(){
        a = document.createElement("button");
        a.innerHTML = "Add";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
    }   

    function inputa(){
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = "21";
        document.body.appendChild(input);
    }

    function ula(){
        ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ulAttr = document.createAttribute("id");
        ulAttr.value = "demo";
        ul.setAttributeNode(ulAttr);
        document.body.appendChild(ul);

        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = input.value;
        document.ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    inputa();
    button();
    ula();
}
```

Comment: **1.** What's the issue? There's literally no question here. **2.** Where's your HTML? Without that we aren't mind-readers to understand your code and write free code for you. **3.** It would always be better to have a [mcve]. Can you please use Stack Snippets to create one for us?

Comment: What issues are you exactly facing?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ul.appendChild(li); not document.ul. Ok, i guess that on page load all works fine (after this fix), but you need event listener for button click, right? Shouldn't be too hard, try, and tell us if something goes wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/nxan4Lb6/

Comment: Actually, I want to create elements using javascript.

Comment: @sinisake, When the user enter the content on the input box, it should be appended into the ul element.

Comment: There's not correct elements in it.

Comment: Can you please advise where i made mistake?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your code, modified to fit your needs:

```js
function Add(){
var a, input, ul, ulAttr, li;
function button(){
 a = document.createElement("button");
  a.innerHTML = "Add";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.className='add';
} 

function inputa(){
 input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = "21";
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}

function ula(){
 ul = document.createElement("ul");
 ulAttr = document.createAttribute("id");
 ulAttr.value = "demo";
 ul.setAttributeNode(ulAttr);
 document.body.appendChild(ul);


}

inputa();
button();
ula();
function list() {
li = document.createElement("li");
 li.innerHTML = input.value;
 ul.appendChild(li); //not document.ul, as mentioned in comments!
}

a.addEventListener("click", list);
}
```

```html
<p onclick="Add();">Test</p>
```

You need one additional function, and event listener for button:

```
function list() {
li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = input.value;
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

a.addEventListener("click", list);
```

which will create li's and put content in list items.

P.S. i've removed automatic insertion of first li (in ula() function), but you can keep it, if it is desired behavior.

Comment: It's working... Thanks